# Manipulating data in java List<Object> in a structured way

Tags: java, object

I have the following class :

```
class Students{
  int age; 
  int dept;
}
```

Lets say i have a `List<Students>` and I want to manipulate the list by doing simple calculations like : calculate the `mean`, calculate the middle value (e.g. (age+debt)/2), find the closest value to the mean and so on. How can I do this in a structured way?. I want to be in a position where I can use different combinations on the list. e.g. calculate mean of age // calculate mean of the middle value from age/debt, find the closest value of the age etc.

How should i approach this?. Would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "in a structured way".  (Also, it's not clear what (age+dept)/2 would mean.)

Comment: Bet every students have an age.. so why not make functions which iterate through the list and do the calculations you need?

Comment: What does the `List<Object>` in the title have to do with the `List<Students>` in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Math has a nice Descriptive Statistics package that does this sought of thing.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html#a1.2_Descriptive_statistics

If you're using Java 8 this works well with Lambdas:

```
DescriptiveStatistics stats = new DescriptiveStatistics();
students.forEach(s -> stats.add(s.age));
double mean = stats.getMean();
```

And to filter etc:

```
//Only students with an age > 18 
students.stream.filter(s -> s.age > 18).forEach(s -> stats.add(s.age));
```

If you're not using Java 8 then simply foreach it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate class (StudentCalculator) that will require a List of Students (perhaps pass the List in the constructor) and have the instance methods perform calculations on the List.

Or you can create a utility (e.g. StudentCalculatorUtility) where you would define a series of methods that would accept a List of Students as a parameter, that would perform all the calculations you would need on the students(middle value,closest to mean, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept where you step through a list and perform an operation on each item in turn which may or may not change the item.

In this case, you want a method that takes an item from the list does some stuff and returns a running total.

```
int sumItems(Student stu, int sum){
   return (stu.age + stu.debt)/2;
}
```

To use this method, either use either a forEach or an iterator.

```
Iterator itr = Students.iterator();  // assuming List<Student> Students = new List<Student>()
int sum = 0;
while(itr.hasnext()){
   sum = sumItems(itr.next(), sum)
}
```

Now do something with your sum.